# Can you claim books as a business expense?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, education, eligible-expenses

Bill Gates reads hundreds of books a year, most, if not all of which are books that directly help him with his work. In his case, it probably doesn't matter, but for the rest of us, buying hundreds of books a year is not easy.

Assuming the books being purchased are honestly intended to help you at work, could one write them off as business expenses or education related?

Comment: Are you self-employed or an employee?

Comment: One of the easiest way to save on hundreds of books is to use library.

Comment: I'm an employee. Company reimburses for a lot of books, but I'm wondering what all I can do for myself.

Comment: I also visit my county library network, but they're not as up-to-date as Barnes and Noble

Comment: There's the library.  There are online and storefront used book stores. There's Kindle.  There are lots of ways to get reading material at low/no cost.

Comment: @farnsy that sounds like an answer.

Comment: Considering the typical length of a publishing cycle for a physical book, it sounds silly to call Barnes and Noble up to date (compared to, say, the internet).

Comment: Ok, these are all great ideas, but they do not address my question about buying educational material, "discounted" or not,  it'll still cost money, no?

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY: Typical public libraries, at least in my experience, don't usually have the sort of technical books that would be useful at work.

Comment: Visited my local lib 3 days ago. All but maybe 5 books in the entire tech section were 5-10 years outdated. They do have newer stuff (it's a network of libraries) but you need to get in line for 1-3 months. Not terrible, not great. One definitely can't be too cheap when investing in continuing education.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are in the US, based on some things you have said.

If you were self-employed, then expensing books related to your business is a no-brainer and would not cause you any problems with the IRS.

As an employee, before 2018 you could deduct "unreimbursed employee expenses" as long as they were normal and "necessary" subject to a few restrictions. I suspect the IRS would not argue with you about whether textbooks related to your job qualify.

However, this is one of the deductions that is gone (due to the Tax Cuts and Jobs Act). Going forward you will not be able to deduct unreimbursed employee expenses. The exception is K-12 teachers (up to $250), certain military and government employees, certain performing artists, and expenses related to a handicap. So that's a no on your books.  Sorry.

[IRS Guidance](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p529.pdf)